# playframework model not saved properly

Tags: java, playframework

In my `play1.2.4` app,I have a `Customer` who can have a `Set` of `PaymentMethod`s.I tried to model it like below,and also wrote methods in controller to add the PaymentMethod to the Customer.payments.

However,the methods give strange results.When a payment is added,the customer.payments set is correctly shown as incremented by 1 element.Then when I go to another controller method to show the paymentMethods of Customer,it says the customer.payments is empty.

I cannot figure out why this happens.Can somebody help me rectify this?

*Customer.java:*

```
@Entity
class Customer extends Model{
   ...
   @OneToMany(mappedBy="customer",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public Set<PaymentMethod> payments;

    public Customer(){
      ...
      payments = new HashSet<PaymentMethod>();
    }
```

}

*PaymentMethod.java*

```
@Entity
class PaymentMethod  extends Model{
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    public Customer customer;
}
```

*the controller methods*

```
public static void addNewPaymentMethod(Long custId,...){
    Customer customer = Customer.findById(custId);
    PaymentMethod payment = findOrCreateNewPayment(...);//if already in db get it or create a new one
    customer.payments.add(payment);
    customer.save();
    System.out.println("customer  has:"+customer.payments.size()+" payments");
    showPaymentForm(custId);
}
```

***//here the console output is:
customer  has: 1 payments***

edit: findOrCreateNewPayment method is :

```
PaymentMethod findOrCreateNewPayment(Customer customer,String paymentNumber,...){
    String query = "select distinct p from PaymentMethod p where p.customer=:customer and and p.paymentNumber=:paymentNumber...";//other fields omitted for brevity
    PaymentMethod payment = PaymentMethod.find(query).bind("customer", customer).bind("paymentNumber", paymentNumber)...first();//other bind params omitted for brevity
    if(payment == null){
      payment = new PaymentMethod(paymentNumber,month,name,day,type);
      payment.save();
    }
    return payment;
}
```

However,the showPaymentForm() tells me that the *customer doesn't have any payments*!

```
showPaymentForm(Long custId){
    Customer customer = Customer.findById(custId);
    System.out.println("showPaymentForm():: customer has ="+customer.payments.size()+" payments");
    ...
    render(customer);
```

}

***console ouput is:***

***customer  has: 0 payments***

Also,when I checked the Payment table ,I found that

***id |   paymenttype   | paymentnumber | month |     name     | year | customer_id***

28 | PayMethod1       | 1111XXXXXX2222   | 11    | jon        | 2027 |

The customer_id field in this table should have had a number for the customer,but is empty.It seems that customer.save() in the controller did not commit..

Why is this happening? Can someone tell ?..Any help appreciated.

Comment: What does findOrCreateNewPayment look like?

Comment: I have edited the question with the method added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new PaymentMethod, did the Customer get set on the object prior to save?  So something like this:

```
Customer someCustomer = ...
new PaymentMethod(someType, someNumber, someMonth, someName, someYear, someCustomer).save();
```

Also if you expect a customer to be associated with a PaymentMethod you might want to make the Customer field not nullable:

```
@Entity
public class PaymentMethod  extends Model {
    ...
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne
    public Customer customer;
}
```

Comment: do I have to set the customer on the PaymentMethod explicitly?I thought the cascade=ALL will take care of that

Comment: I think because you have a bi-directional relationship in your entity classes you will have to.  See: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/manual/en-US/html/tutorial.html#tutorial-associations-usingbidir